# Flutter : Widget Switch Between Animation

Tags: flutter, dart

I trying to do animation for widget switching position. Image below show A and B widget, I would like to switch between A to B / B to A when button clicked. But at first I have no clue where to start, I wonder is there any plugin are able to achieve, any suggestion could help me, just and some tips, I willing to study the suggestion plugin.

[image]

I tried using AnimatedAlign

```
Container(
height: 120.0,
color: Colors.black,
child: Column(
  children: [
    AnimatedAlign(
      alignment: _alignment.value = _alignment.value == Alignment.topCenter ? Alignment.bottomCenter : _alignment.value,
      curve: Curves.ease,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.5),
          child: Container(
          height: 55,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      )
    ),
    AnimatedAlign(
      alignment: _alignment.value = _alignment.value == Alignment.bottomCenter ? Alignment.topCenter : _alignment.value,
      curve: Curves.ease,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.5),
          child: Container(
          height: 55,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
),
),
RaisedButton(
onPressed: () {
  _alignment.value = Alignment.bottomCenter;
},
child: Text("Switch Position"),
)
```

Comment: did you see this widget ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2W7POjFb88g

Comment: @mohandesR nope, but after i watch, this is not the one, cause what i need is A and B still exist , just switching their position only

Answer (score 1):

I Created an Example ... this is working.I used Animation Positioned

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyClass());
}

class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyClassState createState() => _MyClassState();
}

class _MyClassState extends State<MyClass>{

  bool change = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Title')),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            AnimatedPositioned(
              top: change ?  50 : 150,
              left: 50,
              right: 50,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              child: red()
            ),
            AnimatedPositioned(
                top: change ?  150 : 50,
                left: 50,
                right: 50,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              child: blue()
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 210,
              left: 50,
              right: 50,
              child: Center(
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: (){
                    setState(() {
                      change = !change;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    width: 65,
                    height: 50,
                    child: Center(child: Text("click me")),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        ),
    );
  }
}

red(){
  return Container(
    width: 120,
    height: 50,
    color: Colors.red,
  );
}
blue(){
  return Container(
    width: 120,
    height: 50,
    color: Colors.blue,
  );
}
```

Comment: Manually animating positioned widgets is the nuclear option, and I wouldn't recommend it unless you had no other practical choice. There's a way to do it implicitly with slivers, but I can't remember how it went.

Comment: @Abion47 what is your recommend way to do this